# Как клонировать метки для записей из категорий custom type?

Tags: wordpress

Есть у меня в Wordpress custom type, который называется portfolio, в нем есть категории. Мне нужно клонировать категории в метки для записей. Как это можно сделать, чтобы не заполнять метки записей в ручную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как я решил эту задачу с помощью MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wp_temporary AS (SELECT * FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE `wp_term_taxonomy`.`taxonomy` = 'portfolio_entries')

UPDATE `wp_temporary` SET `term_taxonomy_id`= `term_taxonomy_id` + 1000, `taxonomy`= 'post_tag' WHERE `taxonomy`= 'portfolio_entries'

INSERT INTO `wp_term_taxonomy`(`term_taxonomy_id`, `term_id`, `taxonomy`, `description`, `parent`, `count`) SELECT * FROM wp_temporary

DROP TABLE wp_temporary
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоватся плагинами, например, [Taxonomy Converter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-converter/)

После установки манипуляции с таксономией будут доступны в меню Инструменты->Импорт. Выберете Taxonomy Converter запустить импорт. С его помощью можно копировать/перемещать таксономии между собой.